# react using react-redux-i18n how to use separate locale files

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, react-redux

I'm using the react-redux-i18n package, works fine like mentioned here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux-i18n

But now I want for each language a separate locales file under

```
 src/locales/de/translation.js
 src/locales/en/translation.js 
 ...
```

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is:

```
import {de} from '../locales/de';
import {en} from '../locales/en';
export const translationsObject = {
    de: de,
    en: en
};
```